# How to upload database backup files via FTP in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am busy writing a power-shell script for uploading database backup files to a different location. See my code below:

```
$Dir="\\server\COM\"
#ftp server
$ftp = "ftp://ftp.xyz.com/"
$user = "user1"
$pass = "pass1"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)  

#Lets upload latest backup file
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter *.bak | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |Select-Object -First 1
Write-Output "The latest db backup file is $latest. Let's start uploading"

"Uploading $latest..."
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$latest.Name) 
$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $latest.FullName)
```

I don't see anything wrong with my script but for some reasons, the script is not working and I can't figure out what the problem is. I am getting a error below:

```
Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (534) 534 Policy requires SSL.
```

I am still learning power-shell and not so good at scripting. Can anyone assist?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message is the answer (not an issue with your powershell script).   "The remote server returned an error: (534) 534 Policy requires SSL" Is telling you to use `FTPS` (FTP over SSL) and not `FTP` only.

Comment: @tukan Yes - I tried to use FTPS i.e. ftps://ftp.xyz.com/ but am now getting this error:

Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

Is this how it should work?

Comment: First, why isn't your effort in the question? This is not the way you should work with it. As far as I know you can't use `System.Net.WebClient` with SSL  .  You could use .NET `FtpWebRequest Class` with `EnableSSL` flag enabled.  An example is here: https://serverfault.com/questions/694769/polling-ftps-sftp-server-with-windows-server-2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this script:

```
   #$Dir=""
     $Dir = ""
     $CertificateFingerprint = ""

 $newFileName = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter *.bak | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |Select-Object -First 1

 $Day = Get-Date
 $UploadDay= $Day.DayOfWeek  


 If($UploadDay -eq "Tuesday" ){ 

      Write-Output "The latest db backup file is $newFileName. Let's start uploading"


      Add-FTPItem -Path "" -LocalPath "" -Username "" -Password "" -FTPHost "" 
      Write-Output "Upload completed!"

    }else {
        "Upload failed!"    
    }


 #$DiffBackupDir="\\"
 $DiffBackupDir = ""

 $DiffBackup = Get-ChildItem -Path $DiffBackupDir -Filter *.bak | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |Select-Object -First 1

 Write-Output "The latest db backup file is $DiffBackup. Let's start uploading"

 #Upload of a differential backup to FTP Folder
 Add-FTPItem -Path "" -LocalPath "" -Username "" -Password "" -FTPHost ""
```